# Why does Tkinter's askdirectory() return forward slashes on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

Setup: Windows 7

Python Version: 3.3

I'm making a crossplatform application, and I have the user give a directory using the `askdirectory()` method in Tkinter's `tkinter.filedalog.askdirectory` module. This works fine, except for some reason on Windows it's giving me forward slashes.

Windows uses backslashes, not forward slashes, so when I try to save a text file with native file slashes (config file stores the directory so it has an ending slash I have to add), it looks goofy:

```
F:/Pictures/Wallpapers\
```

The code I use to put the native slash is just `os.sep`, which is the current system's native directory separator, which is different on *nix and windows.

```
    def getDownloadPath(self):
       pathdir=askdirectory()
       if pathdir=='':
           return #cancel
       pathdir+=os.sep
       self.download_location.delete(0,END)
       self.download_location.insert(0,pathdir)
```

Is there a reason the folder chooser doesn't return native slashes? I googled around and saw no answers.

Comment: python forward slashes are perfectly valid in windows

Comment: @joaquin until they mix with other `os.path.join()` in your code, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

I'm going to edit my answer because I don't think I was very clear.

---

To start, `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory` *always* uses forwardslashes in the path it returns.  So, what you are seeing is not a bug--it is a result of the way that the function was designed.  Moreover, this behavior occurs on both Windows and *nix systems.

Now, there doesn't seem to be anything out there that directly states why `askdirectory` was built this way.  Tkinter always did have a reputation for being poorly documented. ;)

However, there are a few things to consider:

1. `\` is a special character in Python strings. It creates an [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).  Thus, if the path returned by `askdirectory` contained backslashes, it is only expected that it would cause problems.  Or, if it didn't, you would still need some safety code to prevent them.
2. Python works just fine on both Windows and *nix systems with forwardslashes in paths.  As an example, this code:

   ```
   open("C:/path/path/")
   ```

   works identically to this:

   ```
   open(r"C:\path\path")
   ```

   The only difference is, with the second method, you have to handle escape sequences.  I did this by using a raw-string, which is explained in the link above.  However, it is a lot easier to just use forwardslashes.
3. Because Tkinter is cross-platform, it is both convenient and efficient to use a normalized path construct internally.  Therefore, why not use the one that works on both Windows and *nix systems without any escaping necessary?
4. If you *must* have a native path for your application, Python already has built-in functions to make it.  These can be found in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module.

With these reasons in mind, it only seems logical to build `askdirectory` to use forwardslashes.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the reason you're providing? If not this is IMHO not an answer. BTW. safer way to change slashes is to use `os.path.normpath`.

Comment: I kind of figured it was for escape sequences, but I feel they probably should have it documented somewhere, because it looks like I don't know what I'm doing if an end user were to open my config file.

Comment: @BartoszKP - While I too would love a link that says what I said, I don't personally believe that my answer is void without one.  I defended my statement with logical reasons and also offered the OP a solution to his problem.  In other words, what I posted was _my_ answer to the question.

Comment: @iCodez Well it's not void, sure. But IMHO it misses the point. The question is "why X", and you say: 1) always X, 2) irrelevant information about backslashes in Python (the fact that backslashes are special doesn't forbid using them, also - `os.path` module uses backslashes on Windows) 3) irrelevant information that Python works with slashes and backslashes 4) Not the best solution to the background problem (using `replace` instead of the right tool for the job - `os.path` module). Perhaps there is just no answer to OP's question - I didn't find it either.

Comment: @Mgamerz: Tkinter is just a thin wrapper around tcl/tk. `askDirectory` calls the tcl/tk command `tk_chooseDirectory` If you look in the tk source files for the implementation of `tk_chooseDirectory` (tkWinDialog.c) you will see that it explicitly converts \ to / before returning. This, because internally tcl/tk always uses a normalized form for paths. It makes writing cross-platform apps easier. Both tcl and python provide functions which return a platform-specific form of the path for those times when you really need a native pathname.

Comment: -1: `\\` is special inside a *literal* string (in source code). It is not special inside a string object (in memory). @Mgamerz: it is not for escape sequences.

Comment: use the following to get windows style path  ;;;;                                                      from pathlib import Path;  folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select the folder'); print(Path(folder))

Answer (score 1):

Windows (NT) actually supports paths defined with forward slashes.
It is possible even to have case-sensitive filenames.
See WinAPI CreateFile - FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS. It is supported on NTFS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx